# LINQ to CheckBoxList data items

Tags: c#, linq, checkboxlist

Im using LINQ to retrive cheched Items  from CheckBoxList control:

Here the LINQ :

```
    IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items
                                       where item.Selected 
                                       select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

My question is why item have to be ListItem type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CheckedListBox was created before generics were introduced, thus the Items collection returns objects rather than the strongly typed ListItem. Luckily, fixing this with LINQ is relatively easy using the OfType() (or Cast) methods:

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                                   where item.Selected  
                                   select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

Answer (score 4):

> My question is why item have to be ListItem type?

Because `CheckBoxList1.Items` is an [ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection.aspx) whose members are `ListItem`s.  That's what your linq query is working against.

Answer (score 1):

> why item have to be ListItem type?

I think because `CheckBoxList` inherits from `ListControl` and `Items` property is inherited from `ListControl`